# BigQuery Standard performance of REGEXP_REPLACE vs RTRIM

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was wondering about performances related to some [RTRIM](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#rtrim) and [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace) in BigQuery Standard SQL.
Which of the following two would be more performant:

`DISTINCT RTRIM("12367e","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")`
versus
`REGEXP_REPLACE("12367e", r"\D$", "")`

I am not sure if there is a big performance change between these two approaches.

Comment: Are you using this in a filter, or in the select list?

Comment: In my experience in order to optimize BQ queries your best bet is learning to use arrays and structs efficiently. As far as differences between functions,  BQ is fast enough to the point where it doesn't really matter which you use in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is much difference unless you have a significant amount of data. I tried a few queries over the [`bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:github_repos.commits) table, applying these string transformations to the `commits` column, which has values like `0000120032a071dcd7e4bb1c8d418ca7a0028431`.

The queries that I tried were:

```
SELECT COUNTIF(RTRIM(commit,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = '')
FROM `bigquery-public-data`.github_repos.commits;

SELECT COUNTIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(commit, r'\D$', '') = '')
FROM `bigquery-public-data`.github_repos.commits;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `bigquery-public-data`.github_repos.commits
WHERE RTRIM(commit,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = '';

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `bigquery-public-data`.github_repos.commits
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(commit, r'\D$', '') = '';
```

These all process 7.91 GB of data (from just the string column) and take between two to three seconds to run, without any query being that much faster than the rest. I intentionally filtered the data such that the results would be empty, since I didn't want to include write time.

Answer (score 0):

The methodology provided in the other answer only covers compute time (real time) and bytes processed. Bigquery does not always dedicate the same amounnt of compute slots to a problem, so I would suggest using slot hours to understand the compute resources required. REGEXP is generally compute intensive, so it'll be more reasonable than not.

In my testing, there was some variance in each run, but I did see that TRIM performed 30% faster (fewer slots) than REGEXP, which is expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).